# "Categorize" or "Mark" SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that SELECTs from multiple databases where column 'auth' = mad:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test.1 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
    UNION SELECT * FROM test.2 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
    UNION SELECT * FROM test.3 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1");
```

How do I mark or categorize the result, obtained from test.1; test.2 or test.3 ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the table name to results:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, 'test.1' FROM test.1 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
                  UNION SELECT *, 'test.2' FROM test.2 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
                  UNION SELECT *, 'test.3' FROM test.3 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, 'test1' as Source FROM test.1 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
UNION SELECT *, 'test2' FROM test.2 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
UNION SELECT *, 'test3' FROM test.3 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just add a column.  Also, it is better to use `union all` rather than `union`, because `union` also expends extra effort to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT 1 as test, t1.* FROM test.1 t1 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
    UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as test, t2.* FROM test.2 t2 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1 
    UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as test, t3.* FROM test.3 t3 WHERE auth = 'mad' LIMIT 1;
```